# Want to change functions between two Raspberry Pi 4 model b units

Tags: retropie, pi-hole

I currently have a Raspberry Pi 4 model B (4gb ram) that i bought and used it to setup Pihole on my home network.  I admit it was a bit overkill but i wanted to implement Pihole before I made my Retropie system.  I had plans to buy another Raspberry Pi but couldn't find one with less ram that wasn't going to break the bank.

I have now purchased a Raspberry Pi 4 model b (1gb ram) which i'd like to run my Pihole so i can use the 4gb system for my Retropie.  I'm assuming it's more than just moving the micro SD card from the 4gb system to the 1gb and plugging it directly into my network switch, but i'm trying to avoid having to redo all the setup i did in the beginning.

Would like some help/thoughts on the best way to move Pihole to the 1gb system so i can use the 4gb for Retropie.

Comment: Swap the SDCards and be amazed. You only need to ensure that the kernel/firmware is up to date and it will "just boot and run".

Comment: Thanks Dougie!! I can't wait to give it a go.  Appreciate the feedback

Comment: What happened when you TRIED?

Comment: I"m still waiting for the 1gb i ordered to be delivered, i was trying to get ahead of things and inquire about how to go about the "switch" before doing anything.  Once i get it all and give it a try i'll let you know how it goes.